# How much detail is required to be on topic?

Tags: support, scope

What kind of information or level of detail is missing from 
[Lyme disease treatment for tourists in the state of New York](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/lyme-disease-treatment-for-tourists-in-the-state-of-new-york)

For instance in comparison with:
[Can I continue vaccines in France? (from the US)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34868/can-i-continue-vaccines-in-france-from-the-us)

@Martin. Thank you.

> you could not tell if the poster was still in the US or had returned to Dubai.

The original Title was “Lyme disease treatment for tourists in ny state”.

> There was also the question of how the poster knew that they had Lymes disease

To repeat, Lyme disease *may* exhibit a rash that is so distinctive that it is virtually conclusive evidence. Ie just looking can be all it takes (even if sometimes more than that).

In any case, questions like this [Visiting Andorra from Barcelona](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35564/visiting-andorra-from-barcelona) have been left open, answered and upvoted without the need for clarification such as of “And how did you get to Barcelona in the first place?”.

> if they had been diagnosed then surely the professional would also have prescribed treatment.

[Rule 2: Don't judge people's motivations for traveling](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/rule-2-dont-judge-peoples-motivations-for-traveling) is actually a “question” that has nothing to do with its Title but given that many people there seem very confused, I think quite likely that some at least of the upvotes (net +23 at present) express agreement with something like “**take the facts provided by the OP as a given** - rather than try to second guess” (eg see @Jonas’s answer).

Your logic is sound, so “treatment not prescribed”, so “not diagnosed by a professional” … so what?

> Also I think the tag was wrong as it referred to New York City, when in the question it referred to upstate New York

That tag was added by @Aditya Somani (the first to vote to close the question, also as it happens the author of “Rule 2 …”

> The question asker also never responded when asked for clarification.

True. The first comment was:

> Are you still in New York or are you in Dubai? And if in New York how did you find out that you have Lyme disease?

For “Are you still in New York or are you in Dubai” see above. For “how did you find out that you have Lyme disease” see above.

> The vaccine question was a little more detailed

Pertinent. This question is about what kind of detail (that “vaccine” has) is missing.

> gave an idea of locations

See above

> (and intended destination)

See above

> The op also responded to a comment

I think failure to do so is damnable but not of itself a close reason.

> and changed title to clarify the information needed.

I have noted “unclear what you're asking”. My question is “What kind of information or level of detail is missing from Lyme disease treatment for tourists in the state of New York” (what ‘equivalent’ change is required for “Lyme”) and though I appreciate your answer I don’t feel it merits an accept. (For what it's worth however, I have upvoted it.)

Comment: I think the second one is stated a bit more general, but other than that, I don't know.

Comment: @pnuts: Are you asking about the details in these titles or in the full questions? If the latter you should give us more details about what's wrong with the full questions. Based on the titles alone both deal with problems facing travellers so would be on topic.

Comment: @hippietrail I think that is exactly his question. One got closed, the other did not. He wonders why.

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with these questions but I do hate inconsistency in application of policies. Maybe you need to edit the question a bit to clarify with some of what you've just told me here in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

I'm newish to this site, but looked at both of these questions.

The Lyme disease question lacked a significant amount of detail, and required more information to be able to answer. At the very least - From the wording you could not tell if the poster was still in the US or had returned to Dubai.

There was also the question of how the poster knew that they had Lymes disease, as if they had been diagnosed then surely the professional would also have prescribed treatment.

Also I think the tag was wrong as it referred to New York City, when in the question it referred to upstate New York

The question asker also never responded when asked for clarification.

The vaccine question was a little more detailed, gave an idea of locations (and intended destination) The op also responded to a comment, and changed title to clarify the information needed.